# TFrame as Component, IDE changes object to inline on first use

Tags: delphi, tframe

I have created a Tframe unit with visual and DB controls. I registered the frame as a component using the sprig approach. The TFrame has a few published boolean properties.

Everything works OK, except I have noticed that if I start the IDE and open a project that uses that component, the IDE complains about the "unknown" published properties. And if one looks at the DFM, Delphi has changed the definition for the frame within the form it is embedded in from "object ..." to "inline ...". If I just close the project, without saving, and re-open it, all is good.

It only happens on the first project open.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You always have to initialize default property values in the constructor. The `default` clause on a property declaration is only used for generating RTTI used by the DFM streaming system. It does not actually assign the property value, the constructor has to assign a value that matches the property's `default` declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I did (eventually) realize that. Any ideas of the auto change of object to inline?

Comment: A Frame embedded in a Form at design-time is supposed to be declared as `inline`, not `object`. If the IDE is complaining when opening the project, it probably has a bug. Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Using XE6. But I have registered the frame as a component. And this bad behavior only occurs when the first project I open after starting the IDE contains that frame component.

Comment: Why the downvote? No explanation? That's really helpful.

Comment: Probably someone who has trouble understanding your question. I know I do.

Comment: I edited out the "aside" about the addition of a component create constructor which was possibly causing some confusion.

Comment: I had already looked at that example on showing additional properties. The alternative of registering a custom module seemed "trickier" than the approach of just registering a component, and won't yield a component on the palette which was the initial objective.

Comment: I think I'm having a similar problem, did you resolved it?

Comment: No, I still get that first use issue.

Comment: Any update on this?

I'm having the same problem with numerous frames... in C++ Builder 10.2.3

Comment: @totte Sadly no. I have moved on to delphi 10.2.3 and have not revisited this issue. Good luck!

Comment: Did you try CCP instead of TFrame? To me frame always felt conceptually broken, and that lead to all kinds of unexepected behavior.  https://blog.dummzeuch.de/delphi-custom-containers-pack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that registering a TFrame does work, but publishing properties almost always does not. I say "almost always" as i had this kind of issue in the past (Delphi XE2 as far as i remember) and there seems to be a bug in the designer deeply hidden somewhere. Debugging this issue gave me no results back then.

I suggest you simply move the published properties to public and set these properties in source code directly. This is a workaround but it works.

Comment: I think another approach would be using Custom Containers Pack. It was developed for Delphi 4 in Borland Moscow before there was `TFrame`, and it is conceptually cleaner. IT exactly was designed to turn visually-efited forms into incapsulated controls, hioding tohose internal coponents and default published properties too. `TFrame` seems conceptually opposite, prohibiting any encapsulation and making properties too.
https://blog.dummzeuch.de/delphi-custom-containers-pack/

I wish there was the same thing for Lazarus, not only for Delphi