# Custom frame's published properties disappear on form file reopening

Tags: delphi, properties, components, delphi-2007, delphi-ide

I'm using `TFrame` as base class for a compound component which is registered in the IDE. When I pick the component from the palette and I add it into a form/frame, everything seems to works good.
The next time I open the form/frame, the frame component appears as a common frame, like if the component is unregistered from the IDE, I mean that:

- All custom published properties are no more visible in the `Object Inspector`.
- Only published properties inherited from `TFrame` are still visible in the `Object Inspector`.
- Subcomponents can be clicked and moved inside the frame.
  [image]

Furthermore, if the property had a value, I get the following error:

> Error reading MyComponent1.MyProperty: Property MyProperty does not
>   exists. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE: Ignoring the error may
>   cause components to be deleted or property values to be lost.

**Step by step example:**

- I've created and compiled a "Designtime and Runtime" package. (Note that, using Delphi 2007, I've obtained the TFrameModule class as explained in [this Ondrej Kelle's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289934/4528159)).

Code:

```
  TMyComponent = class(TFrame)
  private
    FMyCaption : TCaption;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    property MyCaption : TCaption read FMyCaption write FMyCaption;
  end;

....

procedure Register;
var
  delphivclide: THandle;
  TFrameModule: TCustomModuleClass;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMyComponent]);

  //registering custom module for TMyComponent
  delphivclide := GetModuleHandle('delphivclide100.bpl');
  if delphivclide <> 0 then
  begin
    TFrameModule := GetProcAddress(delphivclide, '@Vclformcontainer@TFrameModule@');
    if Assigned(TFrameModule) then
      RegisterCustomModule(TMyComponent, TFrameModule);
  end;
end;
```

- I've added the folder which contains `dcu` and `dcp` files to
  `Tools -> Options -> Library - Win32 -> Library path`
- I've added the folder which contains the `bpl` file to the `PATH` environment variable.
- I've installed the package in the IDE and restarted it.
- I've created a new "Runtime" package with a form in which I've placed a component of `TMyComponent` class.
- The component is appeared as expected and I've set `MyCaption` property to 'AAA'. [image]
- Then I've saved the form and closed the IDE.
- After that I've restarted the IDE, on reopening the same form file, I get the following error:[image]
- I've also tried to follow the same steps without setting any value to the property and I've noticed that the property disappears from the `Object Inspector`:[image]

**Further informations:**

- The `MyCaption` property appear in the `Object Inspector` each time the component's package is recompiled and the `IDE` is restarted. I can see it in the `Object Inspector` until the next time I close and restart the `IDE`, then it disappears again.
- I've reproduced the same problem using DelphiXE7, passing 'delphivclide210.bpl' instead of 'delphivclide100.bpl' to the `GetModuleHandle` function in the `Register` procedure.
- It doesn't seems related to the OS, I've reproduced it on Windows 10 and on Windows XP.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876081/registering-a-custom-frame  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289672/showing-tframe-descendants-additional-properties-on-the-object-inspector and https://wiert.me/2009/07/16/delphi-frames-as-visual-components-dont-forget-your-sprig/ and no doubt many more topics that can be found using web search

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm using Delphi 2007, so I've tried registering custom module as shown in [Ondrej Kelle's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289934/4528159) but I still have the same error. Don't know if it matter, but at the moment, I only need to use my frame as a component and don't really need to add a wizard for creating child classes. Is in this case `RegisterCustomModule` required? (I've updated the question's `Register` procedure code)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've read dozens of pages about custom frames but I don't figured out what I'm doing wrong. New properties disappear after the first time I open the source file in which my component is placed.. I've also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683142/tframe-as-component-ide-changes-object-to-inline-on-first-use) but it has no answer.